# Arrancar android con otro usuario

Tags: android

Buenas tardes compañeros,

Necesito fijar una app en uno de los usuarios que tengo en android (usuario), hasta ahí todo correcto. Tengo otro usuario (propietario) que está destinado a gestionar este dispositivo, por lo que el usuario (usuario) no tiene que tener acceso a este otro usuario (propietario).

En el usuario (usuario) las barras están escondidas, por lo que una vez se entra en este usuario, carga la app deseada y no se puede salir de ninguna manera.

La solución que he pensado sería arrancar de alguna manera en el usuario (usuario) directamente, y buscar otra forma para cambiar dicho usuario si quisiera hacer tareas de mantenimiento.

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jotadrive!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!